# Container div not stretching to contents?

Tags: css, html, position

Hard to explain so here is the problem:
 http://www.givetoagiver.co.cc/about.php

I think it's to do with the position property of the #content and #left/#right divs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `zoom: 1;` and `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;` to the content div.

When you use float for elements. The elements are kept out of the normal flow of the document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what does the "zoom:1;" do? Is it for cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: This is for Internet Explorer :). Don't blame me for the fact that IE sucks :)

Comment: I spend more time adapting code for IE than creating the site itself :P I wish chrome was standard...

Answer (score 1):

since youre using floats
just add `overflow: hidden` to your #content div

Answer (score 1):

You can either add `overflow: auto;` to your #content-div or you add it to your #right-div and remove `float: left;`. I would prefer the second way!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following changes in css file. For "content"

```
#content{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that floats are not being cleared, that is: you have two floated divs inside a container and no clearing.

Suggestions:

Add float:left to the "content" div.

Add a  after your "right" div. And in your css add: .clear{ clear:both }